# python: text file wants to be converted to hcl format for Terraform

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

with python code, text file in list format, we would like to convert for terraform in hcl format.  With expeted format it failed to add double quote "" with list.

Here is list file input.txt

```
spn-owner-adm = owner, reader, admin, net-admin, str-admin, viewer
spn-net-adm = admin, net-admin, str-admin
spn-str-adm =  str-admin, viewer, compute-admin, viewer, reader
spn-my-adm = owner, admin, viewer, reader
```

expected output.txt

```
spn-owner-adm = [ "owner", "reader", "admin", "net-admin", "str-admin", "viewer" ]
spn-net-adm = [ "admin", "net-admin", "str-admin" ]
spn-str-adm = [ "str-admin", "viewer", "compute-admin", "viewer", "reader" ]
spn-my-adm = [ "owner", "admin", "viewer", reader" ]
```

output.txt file errors double quote for each character.

```
spn-owner-adm  = [" ""o""w""n""e""r"","" ""r""e""a""d""e""r"","" ""a""d""m""i""n"","" ""n""e""t""-""a""d""m""i""n"","" ""s""t""r""-""a""d""m""i""n"","" ""v""i""e""w""e""r" ]
spn-net-adm  = [" ""a""d""m""i""n"","" ""n""e""t""-""a""d""m""i""n"","" ""s""t""r""-""a""d""m""i""n" ]
spn-str-adm  = [" "" ""s""t""r""-""a""d""m""i""n"","" ""v""i""e""w""e""r"","" ""c""o""m""p""u""t""e""-""a""d""m""i""n"","" ""v""i""e""w""e""r"","" ""r""e""a""d""e""r" ]
spn-my-adm  = [" ""o""w""n""e""r"","" ""a""d""m""i""n"","" ""v""i""e""w""e""r"","" ""r""e""a""d""e""r" ]
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
myspn_pattn = r"""^spn-.*-adm.*$"""
spnup = []
myfile = "input.txt"
with open(myfile, 'r') as fsp, open('output.txt', 'w+') as fspn:
    fspn.write("spn =   {" "\n\n")
    for myspn in fsp:
        spnmatch = re.findall(myspn_pattn, myspn)
        if spnmatch:
            for line in spnmatch:
                spnname = line.split('=')[0]
                spnrglist = line.split('=')[1]
                #print("\t" '{} = "{}",' .format(spnname, spnrglist))
                spnup = '{} = [{} ]\n'.format(spnname, ''.join(['{}'.format(v) for v in spnrglist]))

            fspn.write(spnup)
    fspn.write("\n")
    fspn.write("\t" "}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `sprnglist` is a string, doing `for v in sprnglist` iterates through the characters. That being said, I couldn't replicate the issue you described where each individual character has a quotation around it, but the output from the code example wasn't the intended result anyway.

If you want to get the desired output, you first need to split the string into the sections you want (each section is split by a `,`) before surrounding it with a quotation and then rejoining it. In my example below, I'm joining it with `,`  for output formatting purposes.

```
import re
myspn_pattn = r"""^spn-.*-adm.*$"""
spnup = []
myfile = "input.txt"
with open(myfile, 'r') as fsp, open('output.txt', 'w+') as fspn:
   fspn.write("spn =   {" "\n\n")
   for myspn in fsp:
      spnmatch = re.findall(myspn_pattn, myspn)
      if spnmatch:
         for line in spnmatch:
            line:str
            spnname = line.split('=')[0]
            spnrglist = line.split('=')[1]
            #print("\t" '{} = "{}",' .format(spnname, spnrglist))
            spnup = '{} = [{} ]\n'.format(spnname, ', '.join(['"{}"'.format(v.strip()) for v in spnrglist.split(",")]))

         fspn.write(spnup)
   fspn.write("\n")
   fspn.write("\t" "}")
```

I would also like to note that the use of `fspn.write("\t" "}")` causes a weird indentation in the output.

output.txt:

```
spn =   {

spn-owner-adm  = ["owner", "reader", "admin", "net-admin", "str-admin", "viewer" ]
spn-net-adm  = ["admin", "net-admin", "str-admin" ]
spn-str-adm  = ["str-admin", "viewer", "compute-admin", "viewer", "reader" ]
spn-my-adm  = ["owner", "admin", "viewer", "reader" ]

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Shorn,  Thanks for educating me and providing a detailed explanation; this will help me resolve my issue.